# Multi-variable complicated singletons

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I have a pair of static fields with a complicated one-time initialization.  I want this initialization to happen lazily, *a la* the standard [singleton pattern](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html).

However, the initialization procedure involves both fields, so I can't separate it into two different singletons.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
class OuterType {
    //...

    static class FieldInitializer {
        public static readonly SomeType field1, field2;

        static FieldInitializer() {
            //Complicated code that sets both fields together
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: I bet these two fields actually belong in a class, and not just for convenience. It seems likely that if they need to be initialized together, that they are used together, and may represent some concept either in the problem domain or the solution domain.

Comment: See: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html fifth option.  You're basically already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper class that contains the references to both your 'singletons' and make that class the singleton?

**Addendum:**
If you really want to avoid the second level of indirection with this approach, you can always do it in two stages:

- create a new singleton that encapsulates the individual singletons (original point)
- create a singleton for each of the original singletons (with separate backing fields) that is initialised from the combined singleton to guarantee that all singletons are initialised atomically